# Pointer and its behaviour with structure and array

Tags: c

If `ptr` is a pointer and it points to a structure then what does the value at `ptr` give?
Is this similar to a pointer pointing to a Complete array and and the value it gives when asked to give its value by using indirection operator?

Answer (score 2):

The value of the pointer (that is, the value *of* the address, not the value *at* the address) is the address of the structure, which is also the same as the address of the first member of the structure.

After that first member of the structure, the other members follow, though there may be padding bytes in between members (but there will be no padding bytes before the very first member), and there may be extra padding bytes at the very end of a structure.

For example, given the following code:

```
struct foo
{
    char a;
    int b;
    float c;
};

struct foo f;
```

We can say that `&f == &f.a` (ignoring type safety). There might be some extra padding between `a` and `b`, and between `b` and `c`, and after `c`. But we do know that, in memory, `b` comes after `a`, and `c` comes after `b`.